# How can I enable/disable a USB filter in VirtualBox from the command-line?

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, peripherals

I'm running VirtualBox `Version 4.2.0 r80737`.

I have a USB keyboard that I usually just want filtered to the VirtualBox, but occasionally I want to free it up so that I can use it in the host OS as well. I was looking at VBoxManage in the [documentation](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html), and saw the promising looking "usbfilter" option, but when I tried `usbfilter add/modify` I got the error:

```
The machine 'your name here' is already locked for a session (or being unlocked)
```

So it seems that it doesn't affect the running machine (at least not through that option). I really just want to be able to programatically do the same thing as going through the menu to Devices > USB Devices > USB Keyboard [0001].

I don't care whether it's from the host or guest OS that I can access it.

Is this possible, and if so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is done with `usbattach` command as described in [manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idp10616272).

```
VBoxManage controlvm <VM_ID> usbattach <uuid>|<address>
VBoxManage controlvm <VM_ID> usbdetach <uuid>|<address>
```

In order to find your VM ID, run `VBoxManage list vms`

For list of USB device UUIDs, run `VBoxManage list usbhost` (you may need to add `sudo`)

Comment: That looks more promising. Now I just need to find my UUID/address. So far I've failed to find anything useful.

Comment: And just after I wrote that I discovered `VboxManage list usbhost`. Hooray! It works!

Comment: The command you posted seems to be missing an argument as it didn't work for me. If you update your answer let me know, I'll delete mine.

Comment: @csga5000 Thanks for pointing that out, I have edited my answer.

Comment: @WayneWerner I have added `list usbhost` to the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The other answer didn't work "out of the box" so here's what I got from his answer combined with looking at `vboxmanage help`:

(You may need to do: vboxmanage.exe, or cd \your\vbox\dir .\vboxmanage)

```
vboxmanage list vms
# Find your vm in the list and note the left string (ex "some_machine_123412341234_12345")
vboxmanage list usbhost
# Find your device in that list and note the uuid
vboxmanage controlvm "some_machine_123412341234_12345" usbattach "DEVICE_UUID"
```

Or to detach:

```
vboxmanage controlvm "some_machine_123412341234_12345" usbdetach "DEVICE_UUID"
```